# Format-Table not displaying a columns data

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am using the powershell command below to read a csv file and match the computer name to the employee name where the last login date is 181 days old. For some reason the Employee_Name column in the output is only displaying {} on each row. Any idea why its not returning the employee name?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Days = (Get-Date).AddDays(-181) 


$Computers = @{}
Import-CSV -Path c:\PS\ComputerNames.CSV | % { $Computers[$_.Computer_Name] = $_.Employee_Name }
Get-ADComputer -Property Name,lastLogonDate -Filter  {lastLogonDate -lt $Days} -Server servername -Searchbase "OU=US,DC=Domain,DC=net" | ? { $Computers.Keys -contains $_.Computer_Name } | select Name,lastLogonDate,@{n='Employee_Name';e={$Computers[$_.Computer_Name]}} | ft
```

Comment: What are your domain and forest functional levels?

Comment: Domain-US-City-Computers   That part is working fine, it returns the computer name and last login date fine. Just the EmployeeName column as all {}

Comment: When I debug and hover over it does show the employee name just not showing it in the output

Answer (score 0):

When you are looking at it in the debugger have you tried piping that field to Get-Member?  I suspect that it is the array that Format-Table is not expanding but the debugger is able to unwind when you mouse over it.  You are defining $Computers as an array.  Maybe you only care about the first element in the array and you can define 'Employee_Name' as the first element of the array instead of the full array (of maybe just one element).